# Excel 2010 Pivot Table - Show Value As

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have set up a pivot table. Two of the fields are "Inseminations" and "Confirmed Pregnant" in the "values" area.  They are the count of dates for inseminations and count of "1"'s as the "confirmed" indicator so we get:

```
       Insemination    Confirmed
March           196           58
April           212           64
```

etc.
What I am trying to get is the "Confirmed" number to display as a % of the "Insemination" i.e.:

```
       Insemination    Confirmed
March           196        29.6%
April           212        30.2%
```

etc.

Tried all combinations of "Show Value As" I could muster but none gave correct answer.

Comment: I can't test it now, so can't give a complete answer, but indra of format value add a calculated field: `confirmed / insemination`.

Answer (score 0):

Building off what Mate Juhasz said in their comment, this is what I did.
I assume you want something like this:
[image]

In order to add a field with percentages, you'll need to create a "Calculated Field". Select any cell in your pivot table, then under the "PivotTable Tools" menu select "Formula" then "Calculated Field"

[image]

The Calculated Field dialogue box will pop up. Title the field (I titled mine "Percent"). Then, click into the Formula box, delete anything that's already there (probably just = 0) except for the = sign, and then select your confirmed pregnant field and click "Insert Field". Then add a division sign ( / ), select the Inseminated field and click "Insert Field" again. Click OK.

[image]

You'll now see a new column on your pivot table. You just need to change the number formatting to Percent.

[image]

All done!

You can remove the Confirmed Pregnant column if you like, so only the inseminated and percentages show up, but you may want to mess with your headers to make it easier to read.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It seemed to be "counting the dates" that was the problem i.e. it did not then like using the "count of dates" in a calculated field in the pivot table.  I added a column in the data =if(date>1,1,"") so I could count the "1" 's and not the actual dates and it seemed quite happy.